# Texture repeat with ShaderMaterials in three.js

Tags: three.js, repeat, uniform

I have a problem with uniform textures and the repeat of them, because with:

```
tex.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
tex.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
tex.repeat.x=100;
tex.repeat.y=100;
```

it doesn´t work. So I searched the web for a solution and I found the following thread on giuthub: 
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/787
the threadstarter has the same problem as I do, but unfortunately the links with the answers don´t work anymore.

What do I have to do when I want my uniform textures repeated?

Answer (score 5):

Are you writing your own fragment shader? If so, you'll need to multiply the UV coordinates by the repeat values, e.g.

```
uniform sampler2D baseTexture;
varying vec2 vUv;

void main() 
{
    gl_FragColor = texture2D( baseTexture, vUv * 100 );     
}
```

If not, http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Texture-Repeat.html contains an example of texture repeating, e.g.

```
// texture repeated twice in each direction
var lavaTexture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'images/lava.jpg' );
lavaTexture.wrapS = lavaTexture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
lavaTexture.repeat.set( 2, 2 );
var lavaMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: lavaTexture } );
```

Comment: Hello Lee thank you for your answer. I am working with this example:                                                http://mrdoob.github.io/three.js/examples/webgl_materials_normalmap2.html
And I tried to repeat the texture this way: var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'textures/test_COL.jpg' );
    texture.wrapS = texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    texture.repeat.set( 5, 5);
    uniforms[ "tDiffuse" ].value = texture;